# NSData to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I have serialized my `NSMutableArray` of JSON Data into `NSData` to transfer it per updateApplication. Everything went as expected and in the WatchKit `didReceiveApplicationContext` - Method also get called

```
NSData *serialized = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serialized forKey:@"myKey"];

NSDictionary *applicationData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[serialized] forKeys:@[@"JSONData"]];
NSError *error = nil;
//Send Message to the iPhone (handle over the goal value)
if ([WCSession defaultSession]) {
    [[WCSession defaultSession] updateApplicationContext:applicationData error:&error];
```

But how can I transfer it back to an NSArray or NSMutableArray? I tried

```
NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:applicationContext options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

But I get a Sigabrt error....

**Update**

```
NSMutableArray *keys = [s allKeys];
NSMutableArray *values = [s allValues];
```

Gives me:
[image]

Comment: `applicationData` is `NSDictionary` not `NSData`. You need to get the `NSData` object for key `JSONData`.

Comment: Since you are storing `jsondata` inside the `NSDictionary`, it looks like you will have to parse twice

Comment: vadian you are absolute right

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData*counterValue = [applicationContext objectForKey:@"JSONData"];
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:counterValue];
```

Did it